# Why Is JSON Truncated During Linux HTML Response Parsing?

Tags: linux, beautifulsoup, python-requests

`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://music.163.com/discover/toplist?id=19723756"
headers = {
    'User-Agent': "PostmanRuntime/7.15.2",
}
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
r = response.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
textarea = soup.find('textarea', attrs={'id': 'song-list-pre-data'}).get_text()

print(textarea)
```

`

In the Linux environment, the matching result JSON is truncated.
the textarea :xxxxxx  ee":0,"album":{"id":158052587,"name":"Sakana~( ˵>ㅿㅿ

I think it's probably because of the special symbols.
How do you deal with this situation?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert from `string` to `JSON object list`
then it can be print a song.

I tested Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows on VS code terminal.
Both are works.

#### Code

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://music.163.com/discover/toplist?id=19723756"
headers = {
    'User-Agent': "PostmanRuntime/7.15.2",
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
textarea = soup.find('textarea', attrs={'id': 'song-list-pre-data'}).get_text()

json_list = json.loads(textarea)

for song in json_list:
    print("album:", song['album']['name'], ", artists: ", song['artists'][0]['name'], "duration: ", song['duration'])
```

#### Result on Ubuntu 20.04

[image]

#### Result on VS code Terminal at [image]

[image]

Comment: Your environment is running. Can you print locale?
I think the JSON parsing failure may be caused by different environment coding.

Comment: my linux locale:

LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

Comment: this is mine, $ localectl
   System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: n/a
      X11 Layout: us
       X11 Model: pc105

Comment: @rui0908 in the headers I added `"Content-Type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8"` and I got the same results as is shown in this answer.